# Geofencing - Finding Contacts from DB which are inside Created Shapes

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary, geofencing

There is a requirement to fetch contacts based on created shapes (circle, rectangle and polygon) from the DB. Those which are inside the shapes. The current implementation bring all contacts and check one by one if a contact is inside the shape or not. It does not work because of the performance issue. It takes very long time and memory to list contacts which are inside the shapes. Does anyone have any solution regarding?

Comment: This is way too broad and open-ended of a question for this site. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Like @Cbroe mentioned, this is a large topic. MySQL has [spatial data types and indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html). In MySQL 8+ they can be used with latitude / longitude coordinates.